# Hoare logic, Hoare triple: Find loop invariant and prove its validity

Tags: logic, programming

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}_0$ and $f: \mathbb{N}_0 \rightarrow \mathbb{N}_0$. The values of variables $y$ and $i$ are in $\mathbb{N}_0$.

Algorithm **A**:

$y \leftarrow f(0)$

$i \leftarrow 0$

**while** $i<n$ **do**

$\quad i \leftarrow i+1 \\
\quad y \leftarrow y + f(i)$

**od**

For $j \in \mathbb{N}_+$, $y_j$ and $i_j$ are the values after going through the loop $j$ times.

> a)$f(x) = 2x$ and $n=4$. Calculate the values for $y_j$ and $i_j$.

$\begin{array} {|r|r|}
\hline j & i_j & y_j \\ 
\hline - & 0 & 0 \\ 
\hline 1 & 1 & 2 \\ 
\hline 2 & 2 & 6 \\ 
\hline 3 & 3 & 12 \\ 
\hline 4 & 4 & 20 \\ 
\hline  \end{array}$

> b)How many times will the while loop be executed for any random $n$?

The while-loop will be executed n-times.

> c)Which value will the variable y have after going through **A**, when $n \in \mathbb{N}_0$ is random and $f = I_{\mathbb{N}_0}$. (For a set M: $I_M = \{(x,x)|x\in M\}$)

$
\begin{equation}
  y(n) =
    \begin{cases}
      (0,0) & \text{if $n=0$}\\
      (1,1) & \text{if $n=1$}\\
      ([\sum^n_{i=0}i]-1,[\sum^n_{i=0}i]-1) & \text{otherwise}
    \end{cases}       
\end{equation}
$

> d)Prove the validity of the Hoare-Triple:
>
> $\quad T: \{0=0\} A \{y= \sum ^n_{j=0} f(j)\}$
>
> - Find a loop invariant I for the while loop in A to prove the Hoare triple.
> - Prove in Hoare logic that I is a loop invariant.
> - Prove in Hoare logic that $\{0=0\} y \leftarrow f(0); i \leftarrow 0 \{I\}$ is a valid Hoare triple
> - Prove that $I \land \neg (i < n)$ implies the assertion $y = \sum^n_{j=0}f(j)$.
>
> Hint: Make sure that "$\land i \leq n$" is part of your loop invariant I.
>
> e)Find an arithmetic expression, which will become smaller after every execution of the while loop. Conclude that for any $n$ and any $f$ **A** will terminate.

How do I find the invariant and prove its validity?

Comment: I think for $f = I_{\mathbb{N}_0}$ they just mean $f(x) = x$

Comment: Yeah now I'm sure.  Part $c$ is an obnoxiously convoluted way of saying "find a formula for $y(n)$ for when $f(x) = x$".  That should help you do the latter parts.

Comment: Is there a language that uses "od" to end "do" blocks? Even unix, which ends if blocks with "fi" and case blocks with "esac" ends do blocks with "done".